# call hive in graphql

Tags: flutter, dart, hive, prisma-graphql

I would like to retrieve `sessionToken` and `authToken` from `Hive`, then put it inside `GraphQLClient`

**main.dart**

```
GetIt sl = GetIt.instance;

void main() async {
  // Register Service locator
  
  await initAuthServiceLocator(sl);
  ....
  await sl.allReady();
  runApp(...);
}
```

**initAuthServiceLocator**

```
Future<void> initAuthServiceLocator(
  GetIt sl, {
  isUnitTest = false,
}) async {
  if (!isUnitTest) {
    await Hive.initFlutter();
    ....
   sl.registerLazySingleton<Future<GraphQLClient>>(() => GraphQLClientGenerator().getClient());

  ....
}
```

**GraphQLClientGenerator**

```
  class GraphQLClientGenerator {
      GraphQLClientGenerator();
    
      Future<GraphQLClient> getClient() async {
        final authUserBox = await Hive.openLazyBox('authUserBox');
    
        var box = await authUserBox.getAt(0);
    
        debugPrint(box);
    
        final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
            'https://xxx/graphqlmf?session_token="Get from box");
        final AuthLink authLink =
            AuthLink(getToken: () async => "Get from box");
        final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);
    
        return GraphQLClient(link: link, cache: GraphQLCache());
      }
    
    }
```

This is how I registered it

```
 sl.registerLazySingleton<Future<GraphQLClient>>(() => GraphQLClientGenerator().getClient());
```

**Error**

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#1bbd2]:
Object/factory with  type GraphQLClient is not registered inside GetIt. 
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
get_it_impl.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 372 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null'
```

It seems like I can't add `Future` when register `GraphQLClient`. What is the correct approach if I want to call `Hive` in `GraphQLClient` since it requires `async-await`?

---

**Edit**

After I change to

```
sl.lazySingletonAsync<GraphQLClient>(GraphQLClientGenerator().getClient);
```

**New error**

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#6665b]:
You tried to access an instance of GraphQLClient that is not ready yet
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
get_it_impl.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 404 pos 9: 'instanceFactory.isReady'
```

I have added `await sl.allReady();` in `main.dart`, but still getting this issue.

Comment: Are you using `injectable` library?

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh ya, sl is `GetIt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@preResolve` annotation from `injectable` library to solve this.

**Edited**

```
@module
class GraphQLClientGenerator {

  @preResolve
  Future<GraphQLClient> getClient() async {
    final authUserBox = await Hive.openLazyBox('authUserBox');

    var box = await authUserBox.getAt(0);

    debugPrint(box);

    final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
        'https://xxx/graphqlmf?session_token="Get from box");
    final AuthLink authLink =
        AuthLink(getToken: () async => "Get from box");
    final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);

    return GraphQLClient(link: link, cache: GraphQLCache());
  }

}
```

This works when you do `build_runner` to auto-generate the code.

**Or**

Use `lazySingletonAsync` by to solve this.

```
 sl.lazySingletonAsync<GraphQLClient>(() => GraphQLClientGenerator().getClient);
```

Comment: where should I put this?

Comment: Are you manually register all object?

Comment: If I remove the async-await in `getClient`, then register it as  `sl.registerLazySingleton<GraphQLClient>=>(() => GraphQLClientGenerator().getClient());`, there is no error..but if I add async-await, it throws error

Comment: That annotation works for auto-generated codes. I edited code. Can you look at my last solution, that may help you.

Comment: for your last solution, you mean `sl.registerLazySingletonAsync<GraphQLClient>(() => GraphQLClientGenerator().getClient());` ?

Comment: I use your last solution, but get this `You tried to access an instance of GraphQLClient that is not ready yet`

Comment: Sorry, try with this`sl.lazySingletonAsync<GraphQLClient>(GraphQLClientGenerator().getClient);`

Comment: Where are you using the reference of `GraphQLClient`?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the new error, I use `isReady`.

```
GetIt.I.isReady<GraphQLClient>().then((_) {
    runApp(EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('zh', '')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      child: const App(),
    ));
  });
```